# Как разложить JSON структуру в плоскую таблицу (CSV)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas, обработка-данных

Есть такая JSON структура (упрощенный вариант):

```
[
    {
        "Код": "p12",
        "Название": "HN088",
        "Экстра": {
            "Ширина": "360 мм",
            "Глубина": "175 мм",
            "Толщина": "22.8 мм",
            "Вес": "2100 г",
            "Цвет": "Серый"
        }
    },
    {
        "Код": "p14",
        "Название": "HN092",
        "Экстра": {
            "Ширина": "300 мм",
            "Глубина": "270 мм",
            "Толщина": "19.4 мм",
            "Вес": "2330 г"
        }
    }
]
```

Такой JSON на раз раскладывается в Pandas/tablib итп. И все бы ничего, да в итоге нужна плоская таблица именно такого формата:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Код | Название |  Тип   | Значение |   Тип   | Значение |   Тип   | Значение | Тип | Значение | Тип  | Значение |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| p12 |  HN088   | Ширина | 360 мм   | Глубина |  175 мм  | Толщина | 22.8 мм  | Вес |  2100 г  | Цвет |  Серый   |
| p14 |  HN092   | Ширина | 300 мм   | Глубина |  270 мм  | Толщина | 19.4 мм  | Вес |  2330 г  | Цвет |          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Т.е. каждый ключ у `"Экстра"` (вложенного словаря) становится значением в столбце `Тип` на всю высоту самой таблицы (даже если ключ встречается хотя бы один раз, как здесь `"Цвет"`), которая зависит от количества корневых словарей в корневом списке JSON, а значение ключа должно соотносится только к своему ключу. Как-то запутанно звучит, извините.

Примеры выглядят понятнее, чем моя попытка объяснить.

В общем, с Pandas мне удается разложить только вида:

```
------------------
Код | Название | Экстра.Ширина | Экстра.Глубина | Экстра.Толщина | Экстра.Вес | Экстра.Цвет
p12 |  HN088   |    360 мм     |    175 мм      |     22.8 мм    |    2100 г  |    Серый
p14 |  HN092   |    300 мм     |    270 мм      |     19.4 мм    |    2330 г  |
```

Может, кто-то сталкивался с похожим или знает, как такое сделать на том же Pandas?

Или, что было бы лучше, на чистом Python, чтобы увидеть сам алгоритм и быстрее понять, а не подкапотную магию Pandas.

Comment: Дубликаты в именах столбцов могут в будущем вылиться в неслабую проблему - вас это не смущает? В общем эта же проблема также помешает привести нормальное "пандасное" решение - придется лепить "костыли"... Лично я не люблю "костыли" поэтому даже не буду пытаться... Может кто-то другой небрезгливый даст вам ответ ;)

Comment: Да, меня, мягко говоря, смущает, какого формата итоговая таблица должна получится, но так и только так одна торговая площадка позволяет импортировать данные...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с минимальным количеством "костылей":

```
df = (pd
      .json_normalize(data)
      .set_index(["Код", "Название"])
      .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace("Экстра.", "")))
res = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[::-1]):
    res.insert(0, f"Значение.{i}", df[col])
    res.insert(0, f"Тип.{i}", [col] * len(df))
res = res.rename(columns=lambda c: c.split(".")[0]).reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [409]: res
Out[409]: 
   Код Название     Тип Значение      Тип Значение      Тип Значение  Тип Значение   Тип Значение
0  p12    HN088  Ширина   360 мм  Глубина   175 мм  Толщина  22.8 мм  Вес   2100 г  Цвет    Серый
1  p14    HN092  Ширина   300 мм  Глубина   270 мм  Толщина  19.4 мм  Вес   2330 г  Цвет      NaN
```

Comment: **MaxU**, спасибо огромное! Отличное рабочее решение, проверил в боевых условиях - то, что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_json("test.json")

df2 = pd.json_normalize(df["Экстра"])
for x in range(0, (len(df2.columns))*2,2):
    df2.insert(x, "Тип", df2.columns[x], allow_duplicates=True)

df2.columns = ["Значение" if "Тип" not in x else x for x in df2.columns]

df = pd.concat([df.drop(['Экстра'], axis=1), df2], axis=1)
```

df:

```
   Код Название     Тип Значение      Тип Значение      Тип Значение  Тип  \
0  p12    HN088  Ширина   360 мм  Глубина   175 мм  Толщина  22.8 мм  Вес   
1  p14    HN092  Ширина   300 мм  Глубина   270 мм  Толщина  19.4 мм  Вес   

  Значение   Тип Значение  
0   2100 г  Цвет    Серый  
1   2330 г  Цвет      NaN
```

Comment: **strawdog**, и вам спасибо большое! Ваш вариант тоже отлично работает! Вы очень помогли, спасибо!